# Calling clipit from inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, i3, clipboard

I am trying to launch `clipit` from inside a script using `i3wm` and `polybar`. I expect it to relaunch polybar and start all the programs I wanted if they're not already running when I reload i3, but `clipit` refuses to launch unless I type it manually in terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Terminate already running bar instances
killall -q polybar

echo 'Launching polybar...'
MONITOR=HDMI1 polybar default &

sleep 2

# Start applets if they're not running
for arg in "dunst" "clipit" "wpa_gui -qt"
do
    if ! ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -io "$arg"
    then
        echo "Launching $arg"
        exec $arg &
    fi
done

echo 'Polybar launched'
exit 0
```

I have also tried simply putting `exec clipit` in another file, no avail. There are no errors when executing it. Previously, I used `xfce4-clipman` and it worked fine, the only reason I switched is because `clipman` was truncating my history every time I exited i3.

Any advices?

Comment: Yes, they're all in `/usr/bin/`. I call clipit by typing `clipit`. I should add that I've tried `exec /usr/bin/clipit` on another script but it doesn't work.

Comment: No, there are not.

Comment: now it is giving me some warnings about i3 attempting to reconnect to a socket, but I believe that's just polybar.

Comment: It gave me a new error:  `./scripts/launch_polybar.sh: line 9: ./usr/bin/clipit: No such file or directory`. Running `which clipit` returns `/usr/bin/clipit`

Comment: @Clara The error message indicates that it tries to execute `./usr/bin/clipit`, not `/usr/bin/clipit`. When Goro said `./path_to_clipit`, they did not mean to add `./` to the front of the path.

Comment: @Goro The `#!`-line should does not need to change.

Comment: @Goro I removed everything after `sleep 2` and added `/usr/bin/clipit`, but it's still not working.

Comment: @Clara Instead of saying that something is "not working", describe what's actually happening. An appropriate response to "it's not working" is "well, something's wrong then".

Comment: Where are you @clara.? what happened?

Answer (score 0):

In your code the first command `killall -q polybar` will kill polybar and then sleep for two seconds.

`killall` is extremely powerful and its performance is unpredictable, meaning we can't predict for how long it will take to completely terminate a process and its childs.

According to [man](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal):
`killall` is a tool which provide a way to kill a process by its name, it sends signal to a process by its name to terminate it.

> Each signal has a current disposition, which determines how the
>   process behaves when it is delivered the signal.

So you have to control `killall`'s performance.

I think your code would benefit of some revisions. For example, the code should wait until the killing process have been completely finished. You can add a linear after  `killall -q polybar`. This way, the code will wait until the processes have been shut down:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Terminate already running bar instances
killall -q polybar

# Wait until polybar have been completely shut down
while pgrep -u $UID -x polybar >/dev/null; do sleep 2; done

echo 'Launching polybar...'
MONITOR=HDMI1 polybar default &

# Start applets if they're not running
for arg in "dunst" "clipit" "wpa_gui -qt"
do
    if ! ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -io "$arg"
    then
        echo "Launching $arg"
        exec $arg &
    fi
done

echo 'Polybar launched'
exit 0
```